# Python egg_info error and ImportError

Tags: python-2.7, pip, importerror

I have been trying to install and run this pokemon go bot: https://github.com/TomTheBotter/Pokemon-Go-Bot-Working-Hack-API

I installed Python 2.7.12 (32 bit since 64 bit didn't work. I have 64 bit windows) and downloaded + upgraded pip to 8.1.2. The 2 Python paths were created on install and seems correct. I think also setuptools was installed with pip or something, at least it's installed now (v25 or something).

When I'm trying to do step 4 of the instructions `pip install -r requirements.txt` I get this error: http://pastebin.com/EpRwz6B2
Earlier I had another error, but I found out that I needed C++ compiler 10 to fix it. I just hate it when the installation instructions are so bad (It didn't say that C++ compiler 10 was needed).

When I'm on step 7, running the `python pokebot.py -i 1 --cache` (1 for pokemon club user. Doesn't matter if I do it with or without the --cache text, it's the pokebot.py that doesn't work properly) code returns me with this error: 
*pastebinDOTcom/y9MUnymh*

I have absolutely no idea on how to fix this. Do I need an Android or iOS emulator for this bot to work? Fixing the first error should probably resolve the pokebot.py error. I need all the help I can get